# Ruby ExtensionTask: How to make it dependent of another rake task?

Tags: ruby, rake

I am writing a native `C` extension in `Ruby 2.0` with `Rake::ExtensionTask.new('NAME')`. I need to make this dependent on another task that I define

```
task :myTask do |t|
....
end
```

My question is, how can I make this setup such that when I run `rake compile`, extension compilation/creation is dependent on completion of my defined task, ie, myTask?

I tried the following as well, but now I don't see 'compile' option when running `rake -T`:

```
task :myTask

task :extension_compile => [:myTask]
  Rake::ExtensionTask.new("NAME")
end
```

Comment: What is the definition of task :compile? How is :extension_compile is related to :compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a dependency to an existing task you should use the hash notation as you did:

```
task :compile => [:myTask]
```

You don't see the `:compile` task when you run `rake -T` because `rake` only shows tasks that have a description:

```
desc "This is a compilation task"
task :compile
```

Now running `rake -T` will yield:

```
rake compile  # This is a compilation task
```

Comment: Thank you! This did work. However, I encountered another problem. running rake compile now runs 'rake compile:myNativeExtension', which does not have the dependency that we forced on :compile. I ended up adding the following to my original code --> Rake::Task[:compile].invoke. Now, when I do rake -T, only 'extension_compile' shows up and not compile. I can live with that, althoguh I like to find a complete solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your second snippet looks correct, just add the description to be able to see it in the rake list

```
desc "Here's your description"
task :extension_compile => [:myTask]
  Rake::ExtensionTask.new("NAME")
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I already have description in place. I was not able to enforce dependency between :compile and :myTask.